# MVC ViewBag seems to automatically populate TextBox in my View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In my controller I have the following:

```
    ViewBag.VendorName = vendorname;
```

In my View I have the following:

```
    @Html.TextBox("VendorName")
```

It appears that the `TextBox` `VendorName` is being populated with the content of `ViewBag.VendorName`.

This is what I want but didn't know that from a `ViewBag` you can directly populate a TextBox.

Is this expected and why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Steve Sanderson in Pro MVC:

HTML helper methods populate their value from the following places (in this order):

1. ViewData.ModelState["VendorName"].Value.RawValue
2. For string based helpers, the value parameter passed to the helper method, or if you didn't supply one, then ViewData.Eval["VendorName"] (and ViewBag.VendorName as you're seeing here)
3. For strongly typed helpers, the corresponding property value on your Model object